# Есть ли QTabWidget для Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Понадобилось сделать окно с вкладками, QTabWidget подходит лучше всего, но я делаю программу на Tkinter. Есть ли такой виджет для этого GUI или хотябы аналог?

Comment: Есть [ttk.Notebook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('test')

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

f1 = Text(root)
f2 = Text(root)
f3 = Text(root)

nb.add(f1, text='page1')
nb.add(f2, text='page2')
nb.add(f3, text='page3')

root.mainloop()
```